# How should I reset my application using vb2008 except for the last form?

Tags: vb.net

So, I made an application which composes several forms. It contains saving scores at the end of the game(form). However, when I try to reset the game, it resets all the data with this code:

```
Private Sub ResetDataToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ResetDataToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Application.Restart()
    Me.Refresh()
```

I only want to reset all forms except for the scoretable form which is the last form. Can you give me the easiest way to solve my problem?

P.S I am a newbie for this. Please help me guys. This will serve as my quarterly exam. I need to pass.

Comment: I think restarting the application destroys all user and application objects (restarting your car means you have to turn it off first). You can save the last data and then after restart check for the data and if it exists, start from there.

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie Oh, I was suppose to ask another question regarding saving the data but it was said that I am suppose to post another question after 90 minutes.

My question goes like this:

How should I save my score sheet table using vb 2008 after closing my program?

I do not know how to save my data for the score sheet after I close my program. Basically, I only want the "score sheet" (last) form to be saved.

Also, I am linking my MS Access data to my vb2008 program but my problem is, the input made would not reflect to the MS Access.

What should I do?